# retrieving values from a server and setting those values as default for a select drop down using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am creating an update form to enable my users to modify their data and I want to set a default value in my option element of the data they had stored in the database.Here is the code:

```
<option value="{{$car[0]->bodyType_id}}" >{{$car[0]->body_type}}</option>
```

Additionally, I am loading other body types which is fetch from the server using angular http service.
here is the code:

```
<select name="body_type" class="form-control input-sm" required ng-model = "body" ng-options="bodyType.body_type for bodyType in bodyTypes track by bodyType.id"></select>
```

I have nested the default option in the select element and the problem is; the default option does not show up and when I use inspect element in chrome I get this:

```
<option value"?"></option>
```

why is it not showing and Thanks in advance for helping me fix the problem.

Comment: `$car[0]->body_type` is invalid syntax. What does scope look like?

Comment: $car[0]->body_type is not invalid, because I am using laravel 4 blade template and I change the default expression template for angularJS to this'[[ ]]'

Comment: when I delete the value attribute in the option element the value of $car[0]->body_type is displayed

Comment: in order for it to be selected need to set model `body` to same value in scope. `ng-model` is 2-way binding

Comment: @charlietfl okay then